# Need help getting item (struct) by id from list and return that item. (beginner)

Tags: rust, iterator

I want to create a list containing structs. Then get specific item from list and return in a function. What am I doing wrong. Im very new to this language but I have tried to look at the documentation but I would love a helping hand. Anyone know how to do this?

```
struct Foo{
    id: u8,
    name: String
}

fn get_foo_by_id(id: u8) -> Foo {

    let mut foo_1 = Attraction {
        id: 2,
        name: String::from("Foo 1"),        
    };

    let mut foo_2 = Attraction {
        id: 2,
        name: String::from("Foo 2"),        
    };

    let mut foo_3 = Attraction {
        id: 3,
        name: String::from("Foo 3"),        
    };

    let mut listOfFoos: Vec<Foo> = Vec::new();
    listOfFoos.push(foo_1);
    listOfFoos.push(foo_2);
    listOfFoos.push(foo_3);

    let mut iter = listOfFoos.into_iter().find(|a| a.id == id);
    println!("{}",iter.name); //Error: no field `name` on type `std::option::Option<Attraction>`
    iter //Error: ^^^^ expected struct `Foo`, found enum `std::option::Option`
}
```

Comment: If the example compiled, what would you expect `get_foo_by_id(4)` to return?

Comment: [This question was also posted to users.rust-lang.org.](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/need-help-getting-item-struct-by-id-from-list-and-return-that-item-beginner/34236)